# Why are these centered divs shifted upwards and how to fix this?

Tags: css

I don't understand why these two divs are shifted upwards. How can I align them neatly to the center of the viewport? `margin` does not seem to be a suitable method to me. Thank you!

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(black 50%, grey 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

div#center-upper-half {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div#center-lower-half {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center-upper-half"></div>
<div id="center-lower-half"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the body's default margin.
And since your divs positioned relatively to the viewport, the margin of the body is increasing the height of viewport. (Thanks to [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for correcting)

**Solution 1:**

Remove the body margin and it should line up perfectly:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(black 50%, grey 50%);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you dont want to change the body's margin, you need to wrap your divs with a container div and give it the following:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Why does `body` actually have a margin?

Comment: The browser has some default styles it applies. CSS resets are used to remove and normalise these styles.

Comment: But what's the point of a margin on the `body`?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld You're welcome,  I am not 100% sure about the reason but most probably because if no CSS is applied the website should be readable, thats why there are default margins to the body, h tags, and so on.

Comment: So no "content" would stick to the bottom of the page. Now I see. Thank you!

Comment: @ThreeYearOld Exactly, nothing to stick to any side of the page, coz its applied to all 4 sides.

Comment: *And since your divs are positioned absolutely to the body, the body's margin will also be calculated.* --> no correct because the element are positioned relatively to the viewport and not the body and the margin of the body is increasing the height of viewport (hence the scrollbar)